# Как с помощью Java/Kotlin сделать CLI?

Tags: java, kotlin, command-line-interface

У меня есть код на Java/ Kotlin который берет аргументы из String[] args, и мне нужно сделать его запускаем ото всюду из консоли, и без команды Java. Чтобы я мог писать название и далее перечислить аргументы. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Неблагодарное это занятие, но вот тут можете кое-что прочесть https://medium.com/@sulabh4/how-to-make-a-executable-file-from-your-java-code-3f521938ae5c

Comment: После мне просто будет достаточно добавить программу в PATH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы уже используете Gradle для сборки, то вам поможет плагин application. 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Вот пример билд файла, который соберёт jar файл и сгенерирует bat и sh скрипты, которые можно будет добавить в path и вызывать в духе `myapp arg1 arg3`:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.40"
    application
}

version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

application {
    mainClassName = "MainKt"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

(https://gist.github.com/DisPony/d26482cda06b345151127be899cf9a8d)